# What does "if(n/10)" mean in C?

Tags: c

I don't understand what "if(n/10)" means. It doesn't look like division.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    / * printd: print n in decimal * / 
    void printd(int n) 
    if (n < O) { 
    putchar ('-');
    if (n / 10) 
    printd(n / 10); 
    putchar(n % 10 + '0');
```

Comment: I cant post with the question I want to ask. So I just copy and paste a random question.\

Comment: Don't post random code; it leads to more problems.  Why doesn't `n/10` look like division?  What does it look like?  What does division look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional expressions in C, zero is treated as false, everything else as true.

So the statement:

```
if (n / 10)
```

is identical to:

```
if (n / 10 != 0)
```

In other words, the body of the `if` statement will execute as long as `n` is not between `-9` and `9` inclusive. This is the case for all C standards from C99 onwards (C90 had an implementation-defined result when one or more of the inputs to division was negative).

In terms of the code you've provided, it's rife with syntax errors so you'll need to clean that up before getting anything useful out of it.

Comment: What you say about the values of `n` is true on standard C since 1999.    It was not true in standard C before that - In the 1989 C standard, it was not specified whether rounding on integer division was toward zero.

Comment: @Peter, when I speak of C, it's generally the *current* standard, not one from twenty-odd years ago. It's the same reason I tend not to concern myself with TurboC either :-) However, in the interests of completeness, I'll adjust the answer slightly.

Comment: My comment was in the interests of completeness.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand in what conditions it will run. Only 0/10 = 0 right? So it will run as long as n!= 0 ? But in the book the code is written to change number to character string. So how can it test if it's a string?

Comment: @jessie, in C integer division, 0/10 thru to 9/10 will give you zero. So will -9/10 thru to -1/10 in modern C (C99+).